# MUI - Modal close on mousedown (right and middle mouse buttons)

Tags: material-ui

Currently a Modal closes on escape and left button click, would it be possible to make it close also on right and middle button clicks (mousedown event) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the the closed/open state of the modal:

```
function Demo() {
  const [closed, setClosed] = React.useState(true);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button onClick={() => setClosed(false)}>open</button>
      <Modal
        BackdropProps={{
          onMouseDown: event => {
            // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button#syntax
            const isRightClick = event.button === 2;
            const isMiddleClick = event.button === 1;
            if (isRightClick || isMiddleClick) {
              setClosed(true);
            }
          }
        }}
        open={!closed}
        onClose={() => setClosed(true)}
      >
        <p>some content</p>
      </Modal>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

See https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-modal-close-on-right-click-m87sm

Comment: thanks, works like charm. We had the onClose callback on the props,